# Create a custom shape

Tags: android, android-layout, shapes

How to create a custom shape like below image?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i want to create it with xml

Comment: https://github.com/pskink/PathDrawable

Answer (score 0):

Make a new class that extends view.

In the onDraw() use moveTo and lineTo to make the exact shape you want.

In your layout, use:

```
<com.example.yourpackage.YourViewClass android:id...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library **[PathDrawable](https://github.com/pskink/PathDrawable)**

**PathDrawable** is a Drawable that draws simple shapes using Path object.

Answer (score 0):

you should override  onDraw()  method to create a custom shapes

this page may help you

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Answer (score 0):

try this site its generate XML code for Shape

> http://angrytools.com/android/button/